# Importing certificate to Amazon ELB - Skipping Global root CA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I would like to install Digicert certificate ,it comes with Global root CA chain. I would like to skip the Global root certificate while importing it because it causes more bandwith. Is there an option something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the AWS Certificate Manager to import your certificate. Afterwards you associate the certificate ARN with the load balancer. Uploading the full chain is optional. Only required are certificate body and private key. Most browsers will not complain, however I have seen issues in mobile devices when making API calls against LBs missing the full chain.
[Screenshot AWS Certificate Manager Import Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baUAg.png)